# Names of QML nested items

Tags: qt, qml, qobject, qqmlcomponent

I'm trying to parse QML file using QQmlComponent:

```
  QQmlComponent component(&engine,
          QUrl::fromLocalFile("src/WorkModels/MyModel.qml"));
  QObject *object = component.create();
  qDebug() << toJson(object);
  foreach(auto action,  object->findChildren<QQuickItem*>()) {
    qDebug() << toJson(action);
  }
```

But I also need the name of each child Item as it mentioned in QML source. For root it is "MyModel" but how to get it for children? `objectName` is empty for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`metaObject()->className()` for found children gives me what I needed.